# Why does IE11 duplicate content when pressing Ctrl+Z when setting textbox value in onkeyup?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom, internet-explorer-11

In IE11 on Windows 7/8/8.1, if the onkeyup event of a textbox maniuplates the `value` property, the contet is duplicated.

Example:

```html
<input value="abc" onkeyup="this.value = this.value;" />
```

In IE11, click into the textbox and type a character (or delete one). Then press `Ctrl+Z` to undo it. Whatever content is left in the box will be duplicated, instead of the undo operation.

**Edit:**
Posted to [Internet Explorer Feedback on MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/1490199/ie11-duplicates-content-when-pressing-ctrl-z-when-setting-textbox-value-in-onkeyup)

Comment: Ouch. That looks like a delicious browser bug. For the record, it also occurs if you use the right mouse button and pick 'undo' from the context menu, which is even stranger. I haven't been able to find a work-around. Sorry. I can only suggest reporting it to the IE dev team.

Comment: Can not duplicate in IE11 on Windows 10.  Can duplicate in IE11 in Windows 7.  Weird.

Answer (score 1):

while IE11 correct this bug, you can resolve this like :

```html
<input onkeyup="var evtobj = window.event? event : e;if (evtobj.keyCode !== 90 && evtobj.ctrlKey) this.value =this.value;">
```

---